# Using serilog on Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: logging

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1. I would like to replace log4net with Serilog.

How do I configure it for 9.0.1?

Comment: I think this is only possible from Sitecore version 9.1 and upwards.. Refer
1. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/logging.html
2. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/sitecore-host.html

Answer (score 0):

We are using Serilog in our Sitecore 9.0.3 project. It works great. One way of achieving this is shown here:

http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/2019/09/02/sitecore-experience-commerce-improved-serilog-configurations/

It's basically using Serilog and Serilog.Sinks.File NuGet packages.

If you don't like to do the startup.cs way, you can inject a Serilog initialization class after "Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeDependencyResolver" using the patch config and initialize the Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration() as shown in the above url using all the required settings from another config file.

And while using Serilog. Use it like this: using Log = Serilog.Log;

Log.Information(),
Log.Warning(),
Log.Error(),
and so on.